# End to end pipeline tests for apache airflow

Tags: airflow

I want to test a dag in airflow end to end. I have some fixed input data and some expected results.
I tried googling around, unfortunately i can only find information related to unit tests.

Are there some good practices to follow?

I know that i can trigger a DAG run via terminal, but what would be the recommended way to check if the result is satisfying if the duration of the DAG is not fixed?

Comment: In general, when you write ETL, you should have stages that verify the correctness of both your inputs and your outputs. From an Airflow perspective, this would be a task or a process within a task that asserts some "things" about your data.

Comment: A [quick search](https://www.google.com/search?q=airflow+end+to+end+test) returns some results of which [Integration Tests and End-To-End Pipeline Tests](https://medium.com/@chandukavar/testing-in-airflow-part-2-integration-tests-and-end-to-end-pipeline-tests-af0555cd1a82) and [End to End tests using Apache Airflow](https://medium.com/@pedrogalvaosilva/end-to-end-tests-using-apache-airflow-45313379959b) look promising

Comment: Have you seen Airflow breeze yet? maybe it will be good for your purpose https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/BREEZE.rst